# In AngularJs is possible inside a controller to load in a variable an external html template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates, controller

question for angularjs about the inclusion inside a controller of html templates  to set into  variables.This is the scenario.

I've a slider generated automatically with angularjs, and every slide is a page

```
<div ng-repeat="slide in sliders" onfinishrender id="slide-page-{{slide.id}}" class="slidepage" data-page-type="{{slide.type}}"></div>
```

Every slide/page is displayed alone and with all its content, while the others slides/pages are hidden.The content is loaded dynamically only the first time you navigate in the slide/page, and of course it is different for every template. Those base templates are managed with external html files: template.html, template-image.html, template-small.html ...

Then there is a **contentController** that load via ajax the data for every template:

```
// not relevant to post it
```

And a **templateController** that manages all data loaded into the slide/page template:

```
o_app.controller("newsroomCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
  // function that retrieves the html for the content of a subpage
  $scope.fn_get_html_template = function(a_response){

    var a_posts = a_response.posts;
    // loading template.html
    // how to do that???
    // loading template.html
  }
}]);
```

And this is one of the **html** templates:

```
<div class="content-container newsroom" ng-controller="newsroomCtrl">
  <ul class="newsmenu">
    <li>
      <button data-filter="all" class="filter active">All{{test}}</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button data-filter=".news" class="filter">News</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ....
</div>
```

My goal is to be able to load dynamically the html template in the templateController, bind the $scope to the view, set into one variable and load it into one slide/page of the beginnign slider. 
Do I miss something, how could I achieve my goal?

thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need to do this inside the controller? wouldn't it make more sense to load the template in a directive?

Comment: The thing is that, I could have sometimes the same templates but with different data. In that case could I still use more than one time the same directive, filling it with different content, obviously?

Comment: maybe this can help: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Comment: I got it, but can I have an example of the entire process through ajax, directive and controller? Or if you can point out which direction should i take, because I don't get it exactly how it should be, the suggested example is not really as my scenario. Thanks